# error in getting data from database

Tags: c#

This is my code for getting percentage but is returning an empty array. don't know how to solve it

```
List<Employee> employees = new List<Employee>();
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("data source=***.***.***.***;initial catalog=***;persist security info=True;user id=***;password=***;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework");

using (conn)
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT (CAST(Availability as int)/CAST(Functionality as int))*100 from Vu_EquipmentInfo where Vu_EquipmentInfo.MonitoringDate like " + year + "-" + month, conn);
    SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    while(reader.Read())
    {
        Employee employee = new Employee();
        employee.Sanctioned_Post = Convert.ToString(reader\["Availability"\]);
        // employee.Fill_Post = Convert.ToChar(reader\["District"\]);
        employees.Add(employee);
    }

    JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    Context.Response.Write(js.Serialize(employees));
}
```

[image]

Comment: What do you get when you run this `select` command in the database ?

Comment: an empty array like this []

Comment: First, your query is an open door for Sql injection attaks. Read about parameterized quries. Second, you must declare and instanciate the SqlConnection inside the using statement.

Comment: May be because the MonitoringDate is not stored as year-month?
And in the where clause, you only say MonitoringDate, not specify the table again (MonitoringDate instead of Vu_EquipmentInfo.MonitoringDate).
I strongly recommend to launch the query first to see if the query is ok and it matches with the stored values on MonitoringDate and the table.

Comment: I mean running exactly this query in the database: `SELECT (CAST(Availability as int)/CAST(Functionality as int))*100 from Vu_EquipmentInfo where Vu_EquipmentInfo.MonitoringDate...`

Comment: same code worked for me for other queries and yes i will study about parameterized queries

Comment: What is supposed to mean this _reader\\["Availability"\\]);_? Why do you escape the square brackets? Are you sure that this code compiles?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, at first - open connection.

Next, fix your `select` to `select 'exp' as Availability`.

```
List<Employee> employees = new List<Employee>();
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("data source=***.***.***.***;initial catalog=***;persist security info=True;user id=***;password=***;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework");
            await conn.OpenAsync();
            using (conn)
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT (CAST(Availability as int)/CAST(Functionality as int))*100 as Availability from Vu_EquipmentInfo where Vu_EquipmentInfo.MonitoringDate like " + year + "-" + month, conn);
                SqlDataReader reader = await cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync();
                while (await reader.ReadAsync())
                {
                    Employee employee = new Employee();
                    employee.Sanctioned_Post = Convert.ToString(reader["Availability"]);
                    employees.Add(employee);
                }
                JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
                await Context.Response.WriteAsync(js.Serialize(employees));
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

If `MonitoringDate` is a string, you should compare it as such... consider your `where` clause after concatenating the strings (assumed values for year and month)

```
Vu_EquipmentInfo.MonitoringDate like 2017-12
```

*Maybe* you want something like this instead

```
Vu_EquipmentInfo.MonitoringDate like '2017-12%'
```

But the level of information is quite lacking in the question.